# Error: Unbound module Unix in Ocaml

Tags: unix, process, module, ocaml

I started programming with Ocaml 2 days ago, I have been through the basic stuff and I wanted to start trying to create Processes.

In the book I am using the tell me to use the Unix module, so far so good...
But I get this error when I try to run a simple code that prints the time:

```
open Unix ;;
let t = Unix.localtime (Unix.time ());;


Printf.printf "Today is day %d of the current year.\n" t.tm_yday ;;
```

And I get this error:

`Error: Unbound module Unix`

I searched for an answer to this and I found I should compile my code with "unix.cma" linked, after this I was able to compile, but the code does nothing.

I know it might be a very noobish question, but I can't keep going on without this.
Is a library missing?

If I run in top level it says the `#load is and unbound value also`!

Thank you for your time!

**Edit:**

I recompile it with the "unix.cma" linked, and obtained the same error: 
`Error: Unbound module Unix`

Might be a library issue?

I did ocamlc -where and it all seems fine, meaning all the usual libraries are in the PATH, including unix.cma

**Solved**

It was all due to a bad installation of Ocaml. Thank you Jeffrey Scofield

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works here for me. Here is a toplevel session (Mac OS X 10.8.2):

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.0

# #load "unix.cma";;
# open Unix;;
# let t = Unix.localtime (Unix.time ());;
val t : Unix.tm =
  {tm_sec = 39; tm_min = 27; tm_hour = 16; tm_mday = 3; tm_mon = 11;
   tm_year = 112; tm_wday = 1; tm_yday = 337; tm_isdst = false}
# Printf.printf "Today is day %d of the current year.\n" t.tm_yday;;
Today is day 337 of the current year.
- : unit = ()
#
```

Here is a session with the compiler:

```
$ cat doy.ml
open Unix

let t = Unix.localtime (Unix.time ());;

Printf.printf "Today is day %d of the current year.\n" t.tm_yday
$ ocamlc -o doy unix.cma doy.ml
$ doy
Today is day 337 of the current year.
```

If these don't work for you, my only theory is that your OCaml installation isn't complete. What type of system are you using?

Comment: Well I guess it should be something of that nature yes..
I am using Fedora 17 and Ocaml version 3.12.1 (I thought I had version 4.0!)

Comment: I don't use Fedora, but you can ask OCaml where it thinks the libraries are supposed to be: `ocamlc -where`. Maybe you'll see something obviously wrong if you go looking. (PS if you haven't tried it, it would be interesting to copy/paste what I did to see if it works. The OCaml version number doesn't matter for this test.)

Comment: Wait, I tried to compile it again after your answer and I got the error again : Unbound module Unix. But this time, I had the unix.cma linked. So I guess I must have a wrong path to the files?

How can I check that?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to add an example session that fails in the way you describe. It might help identify the problem.

Comment: Ok, so I check the Path for the libraries and unix.cma is there (everything seems fine)

Comment: I found the problem. It was actually a bad installation. I re-installed Ocaml and everything is fine now. Seems you were right and the installation wasn't complete.

Thank you for you time and tips, I am knew to functional programming and to stackoverflow. 

Very very useful, both =)